# Finding peaks and valleys in each column, I'm not understanding this problem

Tags: math

So, to be clear, I don't need help solving this problem, as I know I have the knowledge to do it. The problem is, my English is not good enough to understand technical language, so I don't know exactly what I'm supposed to do.

I've the following excel file:

[image]

And I need to find the ''peaks and valleys'' of each column, and graph them.

I know how to use Matplotlib to graph, what I don't understand is what the problem reffers to with ''peaks and valleys''.

The result should be looking something like this:

[image]

So I'm guessing what ''peaks and valleys'' mean is the lowest and highest value of each column? If this is the case, the high value in Open column would be 24.6875, and the low would be 20.375?

Answer (score 0):

By peaks and valleys it means maxima and minima so find either where the derivative of your function is equal to zero (and curvature != 0) or else where the data reaches a high (low) point then goes down (up) again

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Function to count Valleys in Javascript

```
function countingValleys(n, s) {
let valleyCounter = 0;
let cLevel = 0;
let prevLevel =0;

for (let i =0; i<s.length; i++){
    prevLevel = cLevel;
    if(s[i] === "U"){
        cLevel++;
    }else{
        cLevel--;
    }
    if(prevLevel === 0 && cLevel <0){
        valleyCounter++;
    }
}
return valleyCounter;
}
```